# Read PDF file in specific order

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to convert this [PDF](http://www.novasoftware.se/ImgGen/schedulegenerator.aspx?format=pdf&schoolid=54750&type=1&id=%7B8AB2059C-5F69-4DC8-9F6B-189D74926928%7D&period=&week=38&day=31&width=1440&height=800) into a spreadsheet that looks something like [THIS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BXwXuQoDdOwgan-4bJR-3p4ps_d2fY9f9qM_B53GMzc/pubhtml). But when I copy and paste all the text from the PDF (CTRL+A), the layers are in some weird unpredictable order and looks like [THIS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u4zJrOqG078qiobciO2z-mBAwGIi-GRH4xVp2Sd3LXY/pub).

Is there anyway to copy and paste the text in some kind of predictable way so I can turn it into the spreadsheet I linked to? (I should mention that I'm making an android app, so id prefer the solution to be inside an Android Studio Project, but that might not be necessary)

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could use PDFTextStripperByArea, but for that you'd have to know the areas in advance.

Comment: Creating a custom text extractor for that kind of document would only make sense if you need to extract the text of very many of them and are sure the internal structure of those PDFs won't change for a long time.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I have thousands of documents to extract. Do you have any tips on how I do this?

Comment: If one can assume not only the appearance of the rendered documents to be similar but also the internal structure of the content streams of the documents is similar, one can create an extractor which can produce your desired output in a pretty faithful manner. Thus, the first thing to check is whether the internal structures of (a representative selection of) those documents is similar enough. You can use a PDF inspection tool like the [PDFBox PDFDebugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#pdfdebugger) for this.